# What is the ideal way to handle custom file type dependencies in CMake?

Tags: build, cmake

I'm working on a C++ project where I'm encountering an issue I've also had in the past. Alongside my actual executable, I have shader files that need to be compiled.

Ideally, a file called `hello.vert` in the source directory would be compiled at build-time to `hello.vert.spv` in my build output directory.

**My Attempt**

My current implementation does not work - it seems the output files are not created, and if I replace the `COMMAND` with something like "echo hi", touch the source files and then build, it does not show any output either. This is essentially what I have created:

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)

function(build_shader TARGETOBJ SHADERNAME)
    set(FILENAME "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${SHADERNAME}")
    set(OUTNAME "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${SHADERNAME}.spv")
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTNAME}
        COMMAND glslc ${FILENAME} -o ${OUTNAME})
    add_custom_target(MAKE_${SHADERNAME} ALL DEPENDS ${FILENAME})
    add_dependencies(${TARGETOBJ} MAKE_${SHADERNAME})
endfunction()

build_shader(test hello.vert)
build_shader(test hello.frag)
```

**In An Ideal World**

In plain makefiles, my solution would look like this:

```
test: hello.vert.spv hello.frag.spv
    ...

%.spv: %
    glslc $< -o $@
```

In CMake, I haven't been able to find a way to handle certain filetypes in a custom way - this would make the solution as easy as:

```
add_executable(test test.cpp hello.vert hello.frag)
```

Is there a sane, reliable way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to:

```
function(build_shader TARGETOBJ SHADERNAME)
    set(FILENAME "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${SHADERNAME}")
    set(OUTNAME "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${SHADERNAME}.spv")
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTNAME}
        COMMAND glslc ${FILENAME} -o ${OUTNAME}
        DEPENDS ${FILENAME})
    add_custom_target(MAKE_${SHADERNAME} ALL DEPENDS ${OUTNAME})
    add_dependencies(${TARGETOBJ} MAKE_${SHADERNAME})
endfunction()
```

The `target` depends on `OUTNAME`. `OUTNAME` depends on `FILENAME`.

Comment: Wow, surprised I didn't catch that, thanks! Still curious if there's a better way to handle different filetypes, though.